# How to deploy a ReactJS app built using Create-react-app on Linux?

Tags: linux, reactjs, deployment, production-environment, pm2

I created a ReactJS application using create-react-app, and worked on development. Now I am trying to deploy to a server on DigitalOcean, following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RE2PLyFqCzE).

During the video, he used a ready made example application. The only difference he did was to use `pm2 start app.js` instead of `npm start`

Doing the same, pm2 showed the file is running, but when accessing the url, not working.

How do I do this step? I tried running `npm build` and tried the same steps with no success.

Edit: `npm run build`

Please note that I am a beginner, and this is my first time trying to go to production.

Comment: Do you have something like an express server serving the built files?

Comment: @Li357 No I don't

Comment: That's probably why there's nothing showing up. You need some kind of server running on your remote linux machine to actually serve your built and minified JS and HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Li357 I could be wrong, but I followed his tutorial using the sample node.js app and it worked. It is the heroku sample app

Comment: ...because the tutorial uses express?

Comment: @Li357 My bad. I found a tutorial that uses Nginx, maybe this will help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**1. install serve and pm2 packages globally on the system/server**

```
npm install -g serve

npm install -g pm2
```

**2. run the following command to create a production build of your app**

```
npm run build
```

**3. run the following command to deploy the app**

```
pm2 serve <build folder path> <port> --spa
```

**above command example**

```
pm2 serve build 8082 --spa
```

**4. Check the status of the application following command in the shell.**

```
pm2 list
```

> PM2 can serve static files very easily with the pm2 serve feature. It
> supports serving raw files from a specified folder or you can serve a
> SPA (Single Page Application) with it.